# Elastic Search Heap size issue / Out of Memory Issue

Tags: java, elasticsearch, lucene, heap-memory

I am using elasticsearch 0.19.2 version and when i start my elastic search server it throws following memory / heap size issue. I have set heap size in elasticsearch.in.sh file but still getting the same issue.

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Dumping heap to java_pid8397.hprof ...
Heap dump file created [23111032 bytes in 0.495 secs]
[2013-12-18 10:52:34,862][WARN ][transport.netty          ] [Norrin Radd] Exception caught on netty layer [[id: 0x0cb9a81c, /192.168.1.193:57115 => /192.168.1.141:9300]]
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.buffer.HeapChannelBuffer.<init>(HeapChannelBuffer.java:42)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.buffer.BigEndianHeapChannelBuffer.<init>(BigEndianHeapChannelBuffer.java:34)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.buffer.ChannelBuffers.buffer(ChannelBuffers.java:134)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.buffer.HeapChannelBufferFactory.getBuffer(HeapChannelBufferFactory.java:69)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.buffer.DynamicChannelBuffer.<init>(DynamicChannelBuffer.java:58)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.buffer.ChannelBuffers.dynamicBuffer(ChannelBuffers.java:221)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.messageReceived(MessageChannelHandler.java:98)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:75)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:558)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:777)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.OpenChannelsHandler.handleUpstream(OpenChannelsHandler.java:74)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:558)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:553)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:343)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.processSelectedKeys(NioWorker.java:274)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:194)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:102)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
[2013-12-18 10:52:34,868][WARN ][transport.netty          ] [Norrin Radd] Exception caught on netty layer [[id: 0x53f21ba0, /192.168.1.190:60296 => /192.168.1.141:9300]]
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.buffer.HeapChannelBuffer.<init>(HeapChannelBuffer.java:42)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.buffer.BigEndianHeapChannelBuffer.<init>(BigEndianHeapChannelBuffer.java:34)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.buffer.ChannelBuffers.buffer(ChannelBuffers.java:134)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.buffer.HeapChannelBufferFactory.getBuffer(HeapChannelBufferFactory.java:69)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.buffer.DynamicChannelBuffer.<init>(DynamicChannelBuffer.java:58)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.buffer.ChannelBuffers.dynamicBuffer(ChannelBuffers.java:221)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.messageReceived(MessageChannelHandler.java:98)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:75)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:558)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:777)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.OpenChannelsHandler.handleUpstream(OpenChannelsHandler.java:74)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:558)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:553)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:343)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.processSelectedKeys(NioWorker.java:274)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:194)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:102)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
[2013-12-18 10:52:35,861][WARN ][transport.netty          ] [Norrin Radd] Exception caught on netty layer [[id: 0x0da4791a, /192.168.1.190:60297 => /192.168.1.141:9300]]
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.buffer.HeapChannelBuffer.<init>(HeapChannelBuffer.java:42)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.buffer.BigEndianHeapChannelBuffer.<init>(BigEndianHeapChannelBuffer.java:34)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.buffer.ChannelBuffers.buffer(ChannelBuffers.java:134)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.buffer.HeapChannelBufferFactory.getBuffer(HeapChannelBufferFactory.java:69)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.buffer.DynamicChannelBuffer.<init>(DynamicChannelBuffer.java:58)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.buffer.ChannelBuffers.dynamicBuffer(ChannelBuffers.java:221)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.messageReceived(MessageChannelHandler.java:98)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:75)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:558)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:777)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.OpenChannelsHandler.handleUpstream(OpenChannelsHandler.java:74)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:558)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:553)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:343)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.processSelectedKeys(NioWorker.java:274)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:194)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:102)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

I also tried to run ES server with this command but still getting the same heap size issue.
./elasticsearch -f  -Xms512m -Xmx1024m

Answer (score 1):

Open `java_pid8397.hprof` in [HPJmeter](https://myenterpriselicense.hpe.com/cwp-ui/free-software/HPJMETER) and analyze the results.  At a minimum the tool will tell you if the min and max memory settings you configured were applied.

Comment: thanks amir for your reply. Can you please tell me where java_pid8397.hprof file lies in ES server or in OS

Comment: That file would only exist if you had configured the JVM to do a memory dump when it encountered an out of memory fault, which is not the default configuration.

Comment: Did you look at his stack trace?

Comment: That HPJmeter link is NSFW... please remove/revise

Answer (score 0):

If you use some plugins like Marvel you should check indexes count and their size. Because some plugins create big number of indixes and they can eat all your memory.